# I have two bootstrap pop-out carousels but they overlap each other, and cannot be used independently, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have two Bootstrap carousels which use a button to activate each one. On click of either of the buttons,both slide shows appear overlapping one another, so I do not have control over each one independently, which also makes it look very unappealing.

You may find the two buttons in my CodePen : [click here](http://codepen.io/csapty12/pen/dXKmmY)

So far, I have done this:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-5 text-center" id = "container-2">
        <h2 class="margin about" style="color: #cdcdcd;">Portfolio</h2>
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class = "well">
                    <h1> Click Me 1 </h1>
                    <!-- Large modal -->
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">BUTTON1</button>
                    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/555/000&text=One" alt="...">
                                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                                One Image
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/fffccc/000&text=Two" alt="...">
                                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                                Another Image
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/fcf00c/000&text=Three" alt="...">
                                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                                Another Image
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Controls -->
                                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class = "well">
                    <h1> Click Me 2 </h1>
                    <!-- Large modal -->
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">BUTTON 2</button>
                    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div id="carousel-example-generic2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/555/000&text=One" alt="...">
                                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                                One Image
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/fffccc/000&text=Two" alt="...">
                                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                                Another Image
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/fcf00c/000&text=Three" alt="...">
                                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                                Another Image
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Controls -->
                                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you will see, when you click on the first button, both of the slide shows open, and similarly when you click the second button... the aim is to have both of the buttons to show two different slide shows so that I can make something like a portfolio page. 
Could someone please help me fix this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your buttons you have `data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"`. Switch your `data-target` to target an id, by `data-target="#id1"` and then set it accordingly in your modal.

Comment: I dont think i follow what you mean - I tried that but it didnt work

Comment: OH OKAY! that makes sense

Comment: You should know that what you did in your change is just changing the classes to be unique of each other, which is essentially what id's do. If you had any other styling information passed in by the bs-example-modal-lg class, it is now gone, because they aren't a part of it anymore. It's also highly recommended against doing that because of what I just said.

Comment: perfect! now i understand what you mean, it works now, thank you

Comment: Unfortunately that will still happen. Both carousels are referencing the same library object, so unfortunately you can't intertwine them. What you can do is create your own slide object/counter, one for each button that will fire when you click in or out of the modal and will load or save what slide will show. You will also need to do this to load your slides for each one.